# Tab is not exported from reactstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Attempted import error: 'Tab' is not exported from 'reactstrap'.

other component like Card,Button is work but for Tab and Tabs i get error what should i do ?

```
import {
    Badge,
    Button,
    Card,
    CardBody,
    CardFooter,
    CardHeader,
    Col,
    Tabs,
    Tab,
    Table,
} from 'reactstrap';
```

Comment: Show your export and import please

Comment: Literally, You forgot to add `import { Tab } from 'reactstrap'`.

Comment: i sure i load it like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the document of `reactstrap`, there is no `Tab` component.

https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tabs/